# Tips. ASP.NET C# : Check upload file size

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesize

When client trying to file upload, server need file size limit check.
Actually the best way is .. Check on the client side I mean on web browser
(Safari ,Chrome, IE ... etc) then Blocking Upload files if file size is over 
, before uploaded file on server .

But here is problem . We can check filesize on Chrome or Firefox Before 
uploaded file to server like this below code

```
$("#AttachFile").change(function () {       
     var iSize = 0;

     if($.browser.msie){     
          $("#AttachFile").on( $.browser.msie? ‘propertychange': ‘change’, function(){

               if(f.size.toFixed(0) > 2000){
                    alert("File size over");
                         clear_file();
                    }
            });
}
```

It doesn't  works in IE ! so we never know file size before uploaded 
in server on IE browser But .. here is another problem, It's a specify of 
`maxRequestLength` element of `HttpRuntime` TAG in `Web.config`

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength = "number" >
```

This Elements Checks upload file-size limit and Defaults value is approximately 
4 Megabyes .. and It can't handle on the Handles .. like . alerting to client.
Go to Exception , even if we add file size check code on Server.
So the answer is simple , you should specified explicitly
 `maxRequestLength` high bandwidth

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength = "716800" >
```

like this. you can't still handle over 716800 bytes . but you can check widely
Below code is example of file-size check on server

```
if (AttachFile.PostedFile.ContentLength > 4096000)
{
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "attach"
                , "<script language='javascript'>\nalert('File size over.');\n</script>");

        //Remove Uploaded files code here
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question here somewhere, or am I missing it?

Comment: first of all, if you want to post tips, you need to do it in two steps. 1) post a question 2) post an answer. Otherwise it confuses people. Second, for your solution to work, the file needs to be uploaded already. It kinda defeats the purpose of your tip

Comment: Thx for comments , this post was my first post in stackoverflow . I've been really thx for stackoverflow users for long time, so I wanted to helps to stackoverflow users a little bit that's why I post it this contents . thx for your opinion . I'll follow your opinion next time . John